# LaTeX code for some geometrical object in Springer template

Tags: code

I used Springer template `svmono` for my geometry book. However, some LaTeX code did not display correctly.

In my case, that is the `\vec` and `\neq` command.

I want to write the vector so I use `\vec` for the vector notation. However, it did not display, `overrightarrow` did display but it is quite ugly. So, what code should I use rather than `\vec` and `overrightarrow`?

I also want to use `widearc` and `wideOarc` but when I insert the [`fourier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fourier) package, it did not display.

What LaTeX code and package is compatible with Springer template `svmono`?

**EDIT** As my question still has some new problems, then I posted my MWE here :

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountsec,sectrefs,vecarrow,envcountretsec]{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{type1cm}           
\begin{document}
$\wideOarc{AB}$: directed arc $\wideOarc{AB}$ 
$\widearc{AB}$: arc.\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user guide for `svmono` says about `\vec`:

> `\vec` depicts vectors as boldface characters instead of the arrow
>   accent.

and also gives a class option

> `vecarrow` depicts vectors with an arrow above when `\vec`-command is
>   used.

So

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\begin{document}

$\vec{a}$

\end{document}
```

will give

[image]

and

```
\documentclass[vecarrow]{svmono}

\begin{document}

$\vec{a}$

\end{document}
```

will produce

[image]

Regarding the other part of the question, something else must be going on with your settings, since \neq seems to produce the desired result:

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\begin{document}

$a\neq b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

and just loading `fourier` gives:

```
\documentclass[vecarrow]{svmono}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}

$\vec{a}\quad\widearc{ABC}\quad\wideOarc{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A new requirement has been made in an edit to the question: to solve the conflict between `fourier` and `mathptmx`, you can simply not load `mathptmx` or, if you want to load both packages simultaneously (which I think is not really good), you can use the `savesym` package to change the name of the conflicting symbol, thus preventing the name clash:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountsec,sectrefs,vecarrow,envcountretsec]{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\savesymbol{hbar}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}           
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
$\wideOarc{AB}$: directed arc $\wideOarc{AB}$ 
$\widearc{AB}$: arc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Gozalo Medina: Dear Gonzalo, the vector is quite short, in fact, if i try $\vec{AB}$, it can not cover the whole word AB. 
The second problem of my template is that if i tried to insert fourier package, then the following error was displayed : ! LaTeX Error: Command `\hbar' already defined.
So, what should I do ?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh for the arrow of the vector, instead of `\vec`, use the `\vv` comand provided by the `esvect` package: a little example: `\documentclass[vecarrow]{svmono}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

$\vv{AB}$

\end{document}`. For the second problem, seems like fourier coflicts with another package, and without seeing which packages are you loading it is hard to tell. Please provide a MWE showing the problem (perhaps in a fresh new question, or adding an edit to this question).

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh You're welcome. Please see the last part of my updated answer.